# (JAVA) Error to open an url, need to be authenticated

Tags: java, authentication, url

I’m using this method to open an url, and works fine

```
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String url = "https://abcdefg.com";
    try {
        if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
        } else if (osName.startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open " + url);
        } else {
            System.out.println("SO unsupported");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening " + url);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem now is that I’m trying to enter to an url that needs to be authenticated before to enter (It give me error 403 Forbidden. You don’t have permission to access / on this server). The question is, how I can authenticate before launch the url, so I don’t get the error? (I have the user/pass)
[link to the image, I cant post them yet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewaM.png)

Thanks in advance!

PD: I use that method to open an url because this other one give me this error, before someone ask for it :P

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    //InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();     
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("MalformedURLException-> " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException-> " + e);
}
```

> IOException-> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: why not use a more tested way of working with url like apache httpclient or jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to authenticate your Http request, but that depends on the authentication scheme requested by the server.

Usually you have to create an `HttpUrlConnection` from your `URL` and set the `Authentication` header with the correct value. Search for Http authentication.
Some Http Authentication scheme like *basic* are easy to implements yourself but some are too complex and you should use a given library.

Comment: Mark this question as answered if you'r happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Basic authentication is supported, here's how I'd do it

```
static String readUrl(String url, String user, String pass) throws IOException {
    byte[] auth = (user + ':' + pass).getBytes("UTF-8");
    auth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth);

    URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MadeUpUserAgent/0.1");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(auth));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I can’t find a proper import for the Base64, the 3 ones that give me eclipse don’t recognize the method getEncoder, so I’m going to look for a library.
I have java 1.7.0_80-b15, what its better, the apache commons or the sun BASE64 encoder to use?

Comment: Can’t edit the previous one, oh well... Finally I use the import _javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter_, changing the _auth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth);_ for _String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(auth);_ and the part of the _new String(auth)_ for _encoded_. In any case, I ended with the same problem as the other method of open url when I use BufferedReader  (_java.net.SocketException: Connection reset_).